# How do I pass an Enum as an argument?

Tags: c#, enums

In the code below I am just coverting a string ("medium" for example) to its Enum value.  What I need to be able to do is rather than having Opacity as a fixed Enum type, pass that in as an argument as well so that the function operates on any Enum.  This seems to be proving more difficult than I anticipated, i.e. 'Enum MyEnum' doesn't work.  Solutions anyone?

```
public enum Opacity
{
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}

public static Enum StringToEnum(String str)
{            
    return (Opacity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Opacity), str, true);  // Case insensitive             
}
```

Comment: YetAnotherUser provided the correct answer to the question you asked, but what is the point of wrapping `Enum.Parse`? The `StringToEnum` method adds no new value and only changes the name of the method you are invoking.

Comment: @Mike you are right over here it's just a change of name - although one can enhance this to add multiple validations, support _string names_ to be defined in attributes, implement it as an extension method to simply say  - `SomeArbidObject.StringRepresentingOpacity.StringToEnum<Opacity>` etc etc. Essentially, if you want you can make it much more useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static T StringToEnum<T>(String str) where T : struct
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), str, true);
}
```